# Custom Inbound Authenticator for WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to develop a **Custom Inbound Authenticator** for **Wso2 5.10** and to run a sample following [this article](https://wso2.com/library/articles/2017/04/writing-a-custom-inbound-authenticator-for-wso2-identity-server/).

After I go on `https://localhost:9443/carbon` and the new custom inbound configuration is showed under the tab Inbound Authentication Configuration, but, following the article, when I go on the web app page on *TestApp* application (e.g. `https://localhost:8080/TestApp`) and click on the Login button I receive a 401 http error.(point six of *running the sample* chapter)

The URL configured on the login button (*TestApp*) is:  `https://localhost:9443/identity?sp_id=custom-inbound&CustomAuthRequest=true`

I think that I'm making wrong the service provider's configuration, if so maybe the article is incomplete.
Could someone help me? Is necessary configure a identity provider?

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of WSO2 Identity Server, the endpoints are secured by default. Adding the following config block into deployment.toml will solve the current issue.

```
[[resource.access_control]]
context="/identity(.*)"
secure="false"
http_method="GET"
```

**But** it will allow accessing any endpoint starting with `/identity` without authentication. Therefore, it is good to modify the inbound endpoint to a specific one like `/identity/customauth` and update above config. This endpoint can be updated from the [`canHandle()` method in `CustomInboundRequestFactory`](https://github.com/gokul/sample-custom-inbound-authenticator/blob/0cfef32f0be95669e9754ff718410dba6e7bbdf8/src/main/java/org/wso2/sample/inbound/authenticator/factory/CustomInboundRequestFactory.java#L44-L47) like it has been done [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-jwtsso/blob/1496e3d1a2719a9b29ff6ef1bed54371a10ddad8/components/org.wso2.carbon.extension.identity.sso.jwt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/jwt/factory/JWTInboundRequestFactory.java#L58-L73).

Also this article has been written for WSO2 IS 5.3.0 and might not be compatible with the latest versions. You might have a look at [this repository](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-jwtsso) for an implementation which is written recently.